# "à la" + masculine

Tags: grammatical-gender, french

I'd like to say

> I'm baking a cake *à la* Ramsey.

Here, *à la* means *in the style of*. My problem is: what if Ramsey is male? The French *la* goes with *feminine* nouns. So, should I write the following?

> I'm baking a cake *au* Ramsey.

That might be more grammatically correct in French, but seems wrong in English, since *au* isn't a phrase in English in the same way that *à la* is.

Comment: The only expression in English where I've seen "au" is "au naturel" which is in fact a loanword. I can't be more helpful.

Comment: In French *à la* remains *à la* whatever follows. It's a common (almost mandatory) ellipsis for *à la mode de* or *à la manière de*. With an adjective, *à la grèque* it is short for *à la mode/manière grèque*. In any case, it is simply incorrect (and not understandable) to substitute *à la* with *au* in French.

Comment: Oops. **grecque* (so easy to fall for this [trap](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8975/f%c3%a9minins-de-grec-et-n%c3%a9ogrec)). That is, *greek*, adjective, feminine form.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Literally, *à la* only means (in this case) *in the*. It's an abbreviation of *à la mode de*, which means *in the style of*. The *de* is not governed by the gender of the place/person/etc that follows.

So your usage is correct.

Comment: So -which- usage is correct? 'a la' or 'au'? Because he uses both. Anyway, there is no 'au' in this place in English, it is always 'a la'. Unless of course there is a direct borrowing from French like 'au gratin' or 'au chocolat'. In English the productive pattern is 'a la', so 'a la (something male)' is correct English.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps this might be relevant to the Cookery SE as well.

How about [Turkey à la King](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/turkey-a-la-king/)?

As you say, *à la* means "in the style of". It's reached English and is now subject to English rules, which do not [for the most part] include gender-specific expressions. It doesn't matter whether Gordon Ramsey is male or not: *à la* is used regardless.

Further examples: [Apple pie a la zing](http://www.oceanspray.com/recipes/corporate/desserts---snacks/apple-pie-a-la-zing.aspx); [Pumpkin pie a la Pigalle](http://www.boston.com/lifestyle/food/dishing/2012/11/recipe_pumpkin.html); [Penne a la vodka](http://kriscarr.com/best-of-kris-carr/how-to-make-vegan-penne-a-la-vodka/)

Where an entire phrase like *au gratin* or *au naturel* has reached English, that's treated *en entière*.

Comment: Only sometimes, the degree to which we follow English rules or the rules of a source language differs from case to case, though tending to become more English as we go. In this case though DavidR is correct, *au Ramsey* wouldn't even be correct French, we borrowed *à la* as an idiom that already existed in French, so whether we consider it as French or as English we should have *à la Ramsey*.

Comment: I usually see Italian _alla_ instead of French _à la_ when talking about Italian cuisine, but +1 regardless. English speakers do sometimes try to retain grammatical gender in loanwords (like _Latina_), but we're not consistent about it and often simply don't bother.

Answer (score -5):

'a la' is feminine, so if Ramsey was male, then you would use the terminology 'au', and you don't need to worry about the relations of French to English, because they are two totally different languages, and what makes sense in French doesn't necessarily have to make sense in English. :-)

Comment: This answer appears to contradict itself. Is that _and_ supposed to be a _but_?